# Manipulating Select with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a simple select element that I want to set the value for using dojo. So when the page loads, I'd like some value to be selected. I am having the hardest time trying to perform that action with dojo. I'm not sure if it's because of my lack of understanding (I come from a jQuery world and now have been forced to use dojo at work) but every search comes up with using dijit.form.Select. However, what if I don't want to use their custom select element. I just want to simply manipulate the contents of the plain select.

I know with jQuery I would do something like

$("#select option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');

But I can't seem to figure out how to perform this with dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experimenting with this for a while, and I just found how you can do it. It's basically a mix between Dojo's functionality and plain javascript.

```
dojo.query("#select option[value ='3']")[0].selected = 'selected';
```

Make sure you include the `[0]` , because `dojo.query` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have also run across this lately. Dojo does not provide a (non-dijit) convenience method for doing this. The most accessible way of dealing with this that I found was:

```
var value = '3';
dojo.query('#select option').forEach(function(option) {
  if (option.value === value) {
    option.set('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

On the other hand, the `dijit.form.Select` "class" only seems to add themes and these convenience methods to its enclosed select. You may gain some more value by somehow removing the themes while using the convenience methods.